# How do I break out of a try loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please refer to the following code:

```
import sys
def x():
    try:
        y()
    except:
        print("exception caught")
def y():
    sys.exit()
x()
```

In this instance, the try loop in function `x()` will be carried over to the function `y()`, causing the except loop to run due to `sys.exit()` raising an error. I know, we can change it to raise SystemExit to exit it, but is there a way to break out of the try loop or is there a better way of writing this code?

Thank you for reading and thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: There are no loops.  Loops are constructs that execute the same code multiple times.  You have `try` and `except` *clauses* (which some other people might refer to as blocks or as bodies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `except Exception`, it will catch all commonly appearing exceptions in your code, but not `SystemExit` exception because it doesn't inherit from `Exception`, it inherits from `BaseException`

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is a bad idea to simply use except without catching any errors... So my advice is to go for the other way you mention, like this:

```
import sys
def x():
    try:
        y()
    except SystemExit:
        print("exception caught")
def y():
    sys.exit()
x()
```

Comment: Yes, this is a better idea but would it cause any problems, like a nested try loop or does that not exist?

Comment: No, that would not cause any problems. There is no loop in this code. The try-clause is not "looping" over any code multiple times so there is no chance of running into an infinite loop if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to exit from try block without getting caught by except block, for this just

```
except Exception as e:
```

instead of

```
except:
```

Here is the full code:

```py
import sys
def x():
    try:
        y()
    except as e:
        if e is SystemExit:
            print("exception caught")
def y():
    raise SystemExit
x()
```